# ARMv8 library not installed from .apk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an app that includes a native binary. At the moment, we have only ARMv5 and x86 binaries. With those, we put the binaries into `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libsyncthing.so` and `src/main/jniLibs/x86/libsyncthing.so`, which works fine on all devices.

We now want to add an additional ARMv8 binary, placed in `src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libsyncthing.so`. According to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html), this is the correct subfolder. However, when I install the apk on an LG G4 (which supports ARMv8), no binary is installed into the `/lib/` folder, and the app can't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here you can see that the binaries are all included in the apk:

[image: apk contents]

You can see the full code in [this PR on Github](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android/pull/738/files). The binaries are not included there, but can be generated with `./gradlew buildNative`.

Comment: Ok lets try to solve problem with divide and conqurer technique. I would try to delete armeabi folder and let the arm64-v8a folder alone. Then checking again if there is native libraries. If so there would be conflict for your devices.

Comment: Right, I also tried an apk that only has arm64-v8a (no x86 and no armeabi), which had the same problem.

Comment: Hmm. What about extract apk with a zip tool? So we can check if apk has correct native libraries. We can make sure about gradle scripts.

Comment: [First lines of `readelf -a -w libsyncthing.so`](https://gist.github.com/Nutomic/6944cf5b7c9b8bac365e3a412c5ac5af). I also copied the binary to the phone manually, and could execute it without problems.

Comment: So you found the problem?

Comment: No. The problem is that Android doesn't automatically extract the binary from the apk. Working around this by extracting the binary manually works. But of course I can't expect users to transfer binaries around with adb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured this out myself. The problem was that I was doing

`binary = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/lib/libsyncthing.so";`

As it turns out, ARMv8 libraries are stored in a different location, so this failed. Instead, I had to use this code:

`binary = context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/libsyncthing.so";`

Answer (score 2):

Are you loading the library using System.LoadLibrary, or some other means?

Starting with Android 6.0, if .so files are stored uncompressed and apk is zipaligned (both default with AS 2.2), the .so files may be used in-place, loaded from the APK instead of extracted somewhere else.

You can try setting:

```
<application
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    ...
>
```

to modify this behavior.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't help, because the binary is still not extracted. Note that the same setup works (on the same devices), with ARMv5. Only ARMv8 has this problem. We execute the binary with `new ProcessBuilder("/data/data/package.name/lib/libsyncthing.so).start()`.